# What does MySQL mean by "Major Version", and is MySQL replication supported between 5.1 and 5.6?

Tags: mysql, replication, mysql-5.6, mysql-5.1

I am migrating from some MySQL 5.1 servers to MySQL 5.6 servers. The MySQL docs are a bit unclear if replication is supported between a 5.1 master and a 5.6 slave, and MySQL's documentation is unclear if this is supported.

In terms of version numbers, MySQL seems to follow the norms for [semantic version](http://semver.org/) numbers

- 5.1 has a "Major version" of 5, and a "release level" of 1.
- 5.6 has a "Major version" of 5, and a "release level" of 6.
- MySQL 4, MySQL 5 and MySQL 6 would all be considered "Major versions".

This is documented at https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/which-version.html :

> The naming scheme in MySQL 5.6 uses release names that consist of
>   three numbers and a suffix; for example, mysql-5.6.1-m1. The numbers
>   within the release name are interpreted as follows:
>
> - The first number (5) is the **major version** and describes the file format. All MySQL 5 releases have the same file format.
> - The second number (6) is the **release level**. Taken together, the major version and release level constitute the release series number.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/replication-compatibility.html says replication is supported between one major version and the next highest major version. This wording is pretty ambiguous if replication is supported between 5.1 and 5.6.

> MySQL supports replication from one **major version** to the next higher
>   **major version**. For example, you can replicate from a master running
>   MySQL 4.1 to a slave running MySQL 5.0, from a master running **MySQL
>   5.0 to a slave running MySQL 5.1**, and so on.

The [updated 5.7 beta docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/replication-compatibility.html) sort of simply that replication is only supported between *release levels*, although the manual uses the term "major version". What do they really mean here?

> MySQL supports replication from one **major version** to the next higher
>   **major version**. For example, you can replicate from a master running
>   MySQL 5.0 to a slave running MySQL 5.1, **from a master running MySQL
>   5.1 to a slave running MySQL 5.5**, and so on.

Is MySQL replication supported between MySQL 5.1 and MySQL 5.6? I understand that MySQL 5.1 is EOL on most platforms, but it's still shipped with RHEL6.

Comment: Don't wish to be a smart ass here, but can you test? My **guess** is that it should work, but don't take my word for it! :-)

Comment: I have tested this, and it seems to work, but there are occasional failures. This is why I was trying to figure out if I am running a supported configuration or not.

Comment: Do you have an error log for the failures? I know that erratic failures are the worst! :-) Why not simply upgrade? That's the beauty of Open Source software!

Comment: I *am* upgrading. I'm migrating from a live 5.1 cluster to a 5.6 cluster using replication.

Comment: Taking down the server for a time is not possible?

Comment: This is a production cluster, and I would like to minimize downtime. Upgrading is not currently possible. This is why I am migrating the data.

Comment: You say you have "occasional failures"? My reading of the **5.6** docco is that what you want **should** work. Don't pay attention to 5.7 - it's only in beta anyway. " Important It is strongly recommended to use the most recent release available within a given MySQL major version because replication (and other) capabilities are continually being improved.". So, if I were you, I'd go 5.1-> 5.5, and then 5.5->5.6. If you have a failure - try, try and try again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've confirmed this is a bug with MySQL/Oracle Support. They will update the public tickets when the internal fixes are ready.

To summarize: MySQL replication is only supported between one **release level** (the second digit) and the next; e.g. between MySQL 5.1 and 5.5; 5.5 and 5.6 but *not* between MySQL 5.1 and 5.6. The documentation is mistaken when it says "MySQL supports replication from one major version to the next higher major version."* They mean **release level** or **release series number**, not **major version**. That is, unless they change the terminology in the future.

Replication between 5.1 and 5.6 might work, but it's not supported and not well tested. It's best to for replication servers to stay within one release level of each other, and to use the latest version of your 5.x release.

The bug reports are:

- ["Section should be more clear about 5.5 and 5.6 versions"](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=77721). Now, the documentation is more clear:

> MySQL supports replication from **one release series to the next higher
>   release series**. For example, you can replicate from a master running
>   MySQL 5.5 to a slave running MySQL 5.6, from a master running MySQL
>   5.6 to a slave running MySQL 5.7, and so on.

- A second private bug which I'll add once the bug is made public.

Answer (score -1):

Not strictly an answer, but perhaps a very long comment:

MySQL is very similar to Mac OS X versioning.  Mac OS X was first released in 2001.  MySQL 5.0 in 2005.  It would be just as unfair to compare OS X El Capitan to 10.0 as it would MySQL 5.7 to 5.0.

The History:

Version 6.0 of MySQL was canceled, and 7.x is the versioning scheme of MySQL Cluster, which makes it more confusing to pick a next number to use.

MySQL 5.6 contains [more new lines of code](https://www.flamingspork.com/blog/2013/03/05/mysql-code-size/) than any release prior.  Making the *de facto* major version number the first and second digit combined.

Comment: According to https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/which-version.html the proper term is "release series number". The docs say *"Taken together, the major version and release level constitute the release series number."*

Myself, I'm just looking for consistent terminology.